# C strstr issue, Returning 0 even when should be 1?

Tags: c, strstr

Spent a while trying to debug this. Strstr always returns 0, even when I pass an argument like "town" that should make sense and print 1. What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char tracks[][80] = {
    "I left my heart in Harvard Med School",
    "Newark, Newark - a wonderful town",
    "Dancing with a Dork",
    "From here to maternity",
    "The girl from Iwo Jima",
};

void find_track(char search_for[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (strstr(tracks[i], search_for)) // Always 0 never 1?
            printf("Track %i: '%s'\n", i, tracks[i]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char search_for[80];
    printf("Search for: ");
    fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);
    find_track(search_for);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fgets` keeps ending newline characters (contrary to `gets`).

Comment: @AlexD I thought you were not supposed to use gets ever? Would scanf work for one word answers? Also quite strange because in the book this is from it works fine, though the code online is corrupted.

Comment: I did not say that you should use `gets`. You should not. I just tried to explain why `fgets` does not work. You can use `scanf` or cut possible trailing newline character after `fgets`.

Comment: A side remark. Your comment says: `// Always 0 never 1?` It sounds that you expect `strstr` return `0` or `1`, it is [not the case](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/).

Comment: Note that you could have debugged this for yourself by printing the strings you're comparing properly.  For example, in `main()`: `printf("Searching for [%s]\n", search_for);` would have shown that there was a newline in the string being searched for.  Alternatively, in the loop in the function, `printf("[%s] vs [%s]\n", tracks[i], search_for);` would have shown the problem too.  Running it in the debugging and printing values would also have shown the problem, but it would be a lot easier to miss the extra newline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function `fgets` includes in the string the new line character`'\n'`, that corresponds to the pressed key Enter.

You should remove it before calling function `find_track` For example

```
size_t n = strlen( search_for );
if ( n && search_for[n-1] == '\n' ) search_for[--n] = '\0';
```

Take into account that it would be better to write the function such a way that it would not deal with global arrays that is that it would be more generic. The both arrays including the size of the global array should be its parameters

Comment: It doesn't include the `'\n'` if the input line is too long to be contained in the array (whose length is specified by the 2nd argument); in that case, the line is truncated.